# ansible - copy key to authorized keys file

Tags: ansible

I have created a user using ansible and now would like to copy the .ssh/id_rsa.pub file to the authorized_keys file.

I checked the authorized_keys module but that is used to copy the keys from the host machine to the guest.

Wondering what would the right approach.

```
- name: Adding user  - {{ user }}  
  user: name={{ user }}
        group={{ group }}
        shell=/bin/bash
        password=${password}
        groups=sudo
        append=yes
        generate_ssh_key=yes
        ssh_key_bits=2048
        ssh_key_file=.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated key is returned by the `user` module, so you can `register` the result and then use the key in a subsequent `authorized_key` task.  That is, if I have a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: add user
      user:
        name: testuser
        shell: /bin/bash
        password: secret
        append: yes
        generate_ssh_key: yes
        ssh_key_bits: 2048
      register: newuser

    - debug:
        var: newuser
```

I will see as output something like:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "newuser": {
        "append": true, 
        "changed": true, 
        "comment": "", 
        "group": 21946, 
        "home": "/home/testuser", 
        "move_home": false, 
        "name": "testuser", 
        "password": "NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD", 
        "shell": "/bin/bash", 
        "ssh_fingerprint": "2048 SHA256:Tn6UOl/WYToJCaW3QUnLMWgEfthILIsoCP+534qWzfw ansible-generated on lkellogg-pc0dzzve (RSA)", 
        "ssh_key_file": "/home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa", 
        "ssh_public_key": "ssh-rsa ... ansible-generated on examplehost", 
        "state": "present", 
        "uid": 21940
    }
}
```

So you can add a task like this:

```
- authorized_key:
    user: root
    state: present
    key: "{{ newuser.ssh_public_key }}"
```